# Win10 UWP System CPU / Memory

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I keep having this dream that in 2017 this should be much easier than it looks like it is :)

- I have a UWP app
- I have a XAML page
- I want to show the current CPU usage % in a text box

There are some workarounds out on the web in various forums to get the info I need. [The most complete of which](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1e99785-f8bb-41b3-bb53-d8c13dc38696/system-statistics?forum=wpdevelop) is from March 2016 and brings with it significant problems. In particular, it depends on GetGlobalMemoryStatus which will prevent WACK certification among its other issues.

In theory, [the SystemCpuUsageReport prelease API class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.systemcpuusagereport) will do what is needed once the Creators update arrives, but I have so far found no examples of its proper usage. In fact outside of the MS documentation almost no one talks about it at all.

So the real question becomes does anyone have either (1) a workaround that will pass WACK or (2) a decent example of SystemCpuUsageReport in action.

Update: Since some folks asked yes I have significant programming experience including .net and XAML. The issue is not that I am baffled by the workarounds, I am simply hoping that they have or will become less necessary and I have just missed the answer someplace.

Thanks!
Ken

Comment: I feel like this question is unanswerable unless you qualify words such as "easier", "simple", and "straightforward".  Easier, simpler, more straightforward _than what_?

Comment: To expand on what @BACON said, do you have any programming experience? Any prior XAML experience? Etc.

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully that is more clear now :)